# combine vectors by elements

Tags: r, dplyr

I have an easy task but it's difficult for me to describe it and find it on stackoverflow.

I have three vectors

```
v1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
v2 <- c(2,2,2,2,2)
v3 <- c(3,3,3,3,3)
```

how can I combine them elementwise, resulting in:

```
c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
```

I know that I can get this vector by `rep(c(1,2,3), 5)` , I'm looking for a generic solution for all vectors of the same length.

Comment: This is a duplicate question: `c(rbind(v1, v2, v3))` or for a bunch of similarly named vectors: `c(do.call(rbind, mget(ls(pattern="v\\d+"))))`..

Answer (score 2):

```
foo = function(...){
    L = list(...)
    c(matrix(unlist(L), length(L), byrow = TRUE))
}
foo(v1, v2, v3)
# [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
as.vector(apply(mapply(c, list(v1,v2,v3)),1,c))
```